# How do I restore usual workflow after a breakpoint in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a breakpoint for debugging. But let's say, I don't need it on the first occurence, but I want Eclipse to pause the next time the breakpoint is reached.
How do I do this?

How do I skip it?

Comment: In NetBeans I can set a breakpoint to break only after the _Nth_  time it's hit.  Eclipse probably has a similar feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-Click on the breakpoint. Then click on breakpoint properties..

A window will appear where you set "Hit count" to "2"

Answer (score 1):

When control reaches to that `breakpoint`, press `F8`. This would make eclipse skip (debugging), continuing the flow and stop at the next `breakpoint`.

[Here's](https://github.com/pellaton/eclipse-cheatsheet) eclipse cheat sheet, listing all the short cuts.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you debug the code there are 3 options. You can have multiple breakpoints and at the time of debugging you can decide whether you want to `Step-Into(f5), Step-Over(F6) and Step-Return(F7)`.

For reaching to next available breakpoint, if you press `F8`, it will directly take you to next breakpoint.